# Possible to Interact with Custom Javascript Object Handler

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to migrate the handling of my [bootstrap date range picker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#usage) from jQuery to ReactJS and while I am able to handle most interactions, I am struggling to figure out how I can migrate the following method to my reactjs setup>

This interaction takes the values selected from the calendar component on "Apply" and then sets two hidden input fields that I have that are sent to my server on form submission.

**jQuery:**

```
//Set annotationDateRange value on picker selection
    $('input[name="annotationDateRange"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
        $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
        $("input[name='annotationStartDate']").val(picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
        $("input[name='annotationEndDate']").val(picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
    });
```

ReactJS (I thought add the `handleChange()` to the field would pick up on the calendar selection changes, but it appears they populate the text field in a way that the virtual DOM does not pick up on it):

```
import React from 'react';
import isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual';

export default class DateFilter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
              startDateValue: this.props.startDateQuery ? this.props.startDateQuery: '',
               endDateValue:this.props.endDateQuery ? this.props.endDateQuery:  ''
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        console.log("New Handle Change")
        /*console.log(input + " " + value)
        this.setState({
            [input]: value
        })*/
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            startDateValue: this.props.startDateQuery,
            endDateValue: this.props.endDateQuery
        });
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (this.props.startDateQuery != nextProps.startDateQuery && this.props.endDateQuery != nextProps.endDateQuery){
                this.setState({ startDateValue: nextProps.startDateQuery, endDateValue: nextProps.endDateQuery });
            }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-md-3">
                <div className="input-group annotation-filter-date-range-picker">
                    <p>Annotation Date Range:</p>
                </div>
                <div className="input-group annotationFilterDatePicker">
                    <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" name="annotationDateRange" className="form-control annotationFilterDatePicker" onChange={this.handleChange} autoComplete="off" />
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="annotationStartDate" className="form-control" value={this.state.startDateValue ? this.state.startDateValue : ""} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                <input type="hidden" name="annotationEndDate" className="form-control" value={this.state.endDateValue ? this.state.endDateValue : ""} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: _it appears they populate the text field in a way that the virtual DOM does not pick up on it_ .
 it is not very clear  can you please explain this point?

Comment: So the input field is a text field that on click loads a calendar picker that contains two input fields for the start and end date range. On the "Apply" click within that calendar picker the text field is populated with the start and end date (`startDate - endDate`), but this population is not caught by my `onChange()` method which is why I thought the virtual DOM is not picking up on the change. If I type into the field, then the `onChange()` is triggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **arrow functions** to not lose the Component scope.

```
handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        [input]: value
    })
}
```

**Or** you can just **call it as an arrow function**

```
<input type="text" name="annotationDateRange" className="form-control annotationFilterDatePicker" onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)} autoComplete="off" />
```

In a **NON ES6 way** you can just **bind 'this'** to the function.

```
<input type="text" name="annotationDateRange" className="form-control annotationFilterDatePicker" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} autoComplete="off" />
```

Comment: The code in the question already has `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)`.